# What are the things to lookout for when migrating a FlashIDE project to Flashdevelop?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I'm migrating a FlashIDE Actionscript 3.0 project to Flashdevelop Actionscript 3.0 (Pure AS). I've noticed that assets importing and project structure are different. What are the other things to lookout for when doing a migration?

Comment: library/embeds, code from your .fla file (if there's any) must be updated (e.g. `var tf:TextField;` => `private var tf:TextField;`), in FlashDevelop press F10 for settings (specify flex sdk location in AS3Context menu and path to standalone debug flashplayer in FlashViewer)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of issues when using flashdevelop(and their fixes) here:
http://flashontherocks.com/2010/12/13/flashdevelop-resolved-issues/